# Change UI's menu select blink rate

Tags: macos, ui, classic-mac-os, contextual-menu

Back in System 7 there was an option to change how many times a menu item would blink when selected:

[image: System 7 General Control (gaussian blur)]

Is it still possible to change this setting in modern-day macOS versions? (I am using 10.14.6 Mojave) Looking in System Preferences>General I don't see any relevant setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in Mac OS X there are no preference panes to control Menu Blinking and throughout Mac OS X the selection rectangle only blinks once on click.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_blinking

Comment: Too bad it's been removed. Thanks for letting me know.